# Find the first three stationary points of $f(x) = \ln(x)\sin(x)$ as exact values.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I've found this problem in a textbook, and keep getting stuck.
Here's the question:
Find the first three stationary points of $f(x) = \ln(x)\sin(x)$ as exact values.
I started by finding the derivative, which is:

$$f'(x) = \cos(x)\ln(x) + \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$

I then let $f'(x) = 0$ and rearranged:

$$x\ln(x) + \tan(x) = 0$$

This is where I got stuck. I also tried inputting the question in Wolfram Alpha, but it was only able to approximate the values.
Is it possible that there are no nice solutions and subsequently a mistake in the question? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using stationary point to mean a critical point, where a derivative is $0$? Sometimes authors use the phrase stationary points to refer to fixed points, i.e. solutions to $x=f(x)$

Comment: My only thought was some obscure use of Lambert W, but I have not managed to find a way, I believe there is no analytic solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the discontinuities, it is better to look for some *approximation* of the zeros of function
$$g(x)=x \log (x) \cos (x)+\sin (x)$$ Because of the front $x$ term, the solutions are closer and closer to the solutions of $\cos(x)=0$ that is to say around $(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2} $.

Perform a series expansion around this point and then a power series reversion to obtain
$$x_{(n)}=q+\frac{1}{q \log (q)}-\frac{2 \log (q)+3}{2 q^3 \log ^3(q)}+\cdots \qquad \text{where} \qquad q=(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2} $$ which seems to be quite good.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 1 & 4.8414549 &  4.8425583\\
 2 & 7.9149192 &  7.9149777 \\
 3 & 11.033295 &  11.033306 \\
 4 & 14.163793 &  14.163796 \\
 5 & 17.299034 &  17.299035 \\
 6 & 20.436567 &  20.436568 \\
 7 & 23.575366 &  23.575366 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

For sure, we miss the smallest root which is close to $\frac 1 e=0.367879$ while the solution is $0.352215$.

**Update**

Taking more terms for the initial expansion
$$x_{(n)}=q+\frac{1}{q \log (q)}-\frac{3 \log (q)+4}{3 q^3 \log
   ^3(q)}+$$ $$\frac{60 \log ^2(q)+145 \log (q)+106}{30 q^5 \log
   ^5(q)}-$$ $$\frac{120 \log ^3(q)+416 \log ^2(q)+544 \log
   (q)+261}{24 q^7 \log ^7(q)}+$$ $$\frac{336 \log ^4(q)+1738 \log
   ^3(q)+3762 \log ^2(q)+3969 \log (q)+1701}{24 q^9 \log
   ^9(q)}+\cdots$$  which gives $x_{(1)}=\color{red}{4.8425}656$  and $x_{(2)}=\color{red}{7.9149777}$

Comment: Thank you for the approximation method. Is it impossible to express the stationary points as exact values? If so, how could that be proven?

Comment: Facing a transcendental équation, by définitions no hope AT all. If this IS answer, may bé, you could accepte it. Cheers